# How to reverse remote mySQL access?

Tags: mysql, database, apache, security

I used the following commands in the process of enabling remote mySQL access to my db (along with the typical required my.cnf) changes:

```
mysql> update db set Host='123.123.123.123' where Db='yourdatabasename';
mysql> update user set Host='123.123.123.123' where user='yourdatabaseUsername';
```

How do I reverse this back to a configuration that does not allow external connections?

I'm getting uneasy about the idea of having this setup this way and don't want to create a security issue.  Also are there any recommended tools I can use to scan my mySQL implementation for security holes that might be caused by misconfigurations?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can simply execute the commands but with "localhost" as the `Host='localhost'` parameter.

```
mysql> update db set Host='localhost' where Db='yourdatabasename';
mysql> update user set Host='localhost' where user='yourdatabaseUsername';
```

Further, here's some good information about securing your MySQL installation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-secure-installation.html